# DataGridView in a Panel Scroll Resetting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar, panel

My problem is exactly the same as:

[Problem with DataGridView and scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140355/problem-with-datagridview-and-scroll-position)

Every time I edit a cell in a `DataGridView` the parent panel resets its scroll bars. This also happens on when the selection in the `DataGridView` changes. I, however, need to keep the panel as I have two `DataGridViews` in it and want to be able to scroll through them both.

I have managed to alleviate some of the problem by listening to the `Scroll` event of the panel, keeping track of the values of the scrollbars, and reapplying these values in the `SelectionChange` and `CellEndEdit` events on the `DataGridViews`, however this doesn't feel like a very good solution and it makes the screen jitter as the scroll changes to 0 and then back to the value that I set it too. Can anyone point me in a better direction, or know of a way to stop the Panel from resetting its scroll bars?

Comment: Am I missing something? Is the question unclear? Is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround that works here:

http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/c-panel-resets-scroll-position-after-focus-is-lost-and-regained/

By overriding `ScrollToControl` and returning `this.DisplayRectangle.Location` it fixed the scroll issue I was having.

```
protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl)
{
    return this.DisplayRectangle.Location;
}
```